# pagePiling js, add stop when reach top/bottom of section

Tags: jquery, pagepiling.js

I was wondering if it is possible in [pagePiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js) to add a stop once the top/bottom of a section has been reached?

My main issue, is using the touch pad on a MBPro, if you scroll quickly it will hit the top/bottom of a section and quickly transition to the next section. I would, instead, like for it to stop when reaching a top/bottom boundary, and then require an additional scroll to make the transition.

**EDIT**: Normal sections do have somewhat of a delay, the problem is on sections using the `.pp-scrollable` where scrolling to the top/bottom of a section will quickly transition to the next section. It would be nice, if in the `.pp-scrollable` sections, an additional scroll is needed to proceed to a different section.

Answer (score 0):

It is not gonna be an easy problem to solve due to the kinetic scrolling of your Apple laptop.

You can read a more detailed description of the problem and a small improvement in [this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/941) of fullPage.js, the bigger brother of pagePiling.js.

Comment: I do like that implementation, it works well. The thing I didn't like about fullPage.js is the scrollable sections. They use slimscroll so there is no kinetic scrolling :( ... This is the main reason I chose pagePiling, since it implements the default scrollbar/scrolling on scrollable sections.

Comment: pagePiling.js scrollable sections won´t work in mobile.

Comment: I know, yet another issue I'm running into. I love both plugins, but neither is the "optimal" solution. As even though fullPage offers mobile scrolling, it is less than desirable. I've been trying to integrate iScroll with it, but so far the results aren't quite successful... I've tried implementing it within the "createSlimScrolling" function, but it seems it doesn't play nice with fullPage...

Comment: @shparkison I believe that a good designed website shouldn't use scrollable sections. It should adapt the content to the device viewport, by using media queries or similar, and probably use the `responsive` option of fullPage.js. Then set the sections to `height:auto` as detailed [in this post](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1044#issuecomment-75812112)